# How do I automate xlsx to pdf conversion in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, libreoffice, unoconv

I hope you´re all doing well. As the title mentions, I´ve been looking for a way to automate file conversion from xlsx to pdf in node js. I found the Convert API https://www.convertapi.com/ which seemed to work pretty well after I tried it but requires a monthly payment, which I´d prefer to avoid.

Someone suggested using the unoconv command line tool along with the child_process module in node, but frankly I´m at a complete loss. Im not very well versed in the command line and even the instructions to install it confuse me a bit:

Here´s a link to the instructions: https://scholarlms.net/universal-office-converter-unoconv/

How can I carry out the conversions without having to use the paid API?

Comment: A link to the instructions would assist us, especially because your provided version is incorrect, _(invalid file paths)_. We also need to know what specifically you're looking for, a fix for your unoconv command, a problem with your batch file code, an issue with your javascript, or alternative methods of performing the required task without having to pay a monthly subscription for the Convert API. This site is supposed to be for a single specific and reproducible issue with your provided code, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63540594/edit) to focus it as such.

Comment: I intend to do the latter (converting without a paid API) and have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: The URL you've provided clearly links to a web page which has not been written to properly display file paths in Windows; do not use it. I would suggest that you try to get the information you need from the [proper location](https://github.com/unoconv/unoconv) instead.